# installed programs not displayed on desktop

Tags: configuration, desktop-environments

Ubuntu installs certain software.  Any other programs are not displayed on the desktop.  How can I place them on desktop to use?

Answer (score 0):

You have good guide on this link, if you use Unity

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UnityLaunchersAndDesktopFiles